# How to mount a Host folder in minikube VM

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have a use case where I need a Docker container under kubernetes to access a hostPath. I'm using minikube, and the container is able to access a folder in the minikube VirtualBox VM. But I can't figure out how to get it to access a folder on the host itself.

I do these commands on the host to create /opt/foo for sharing in the VM:

```
$ sudo touch /opt/foo/FOO
$ ls /opt/foo
FOO
$ minikube mount -v 5 /opt/foo:/opt/foo
Mounting /opt/foo into /opt/foo on the minikubeVM
This daemon process needs to stay alive for the mount to still be accessible...
ufs starting
```

In another window I look in the minikube VM

```
$ minikube ssh -- sudo ls -la /opt/foo
total 0
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 0 Jun  1 14:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 0 Jun  1 14:44 ..
```

Is there another step needed to make the files in that directory accessible?

FYI - use case is a container process creating files that a host process is harvesting. Thus I do not want to use nfs or PersistentVolumes. Host is Centos7. minikube version: v0.19.0.

Comment: it works fine for me with similar folders

Comment: Seems like my issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2300

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the firewall, in Ubuntu this worked for me:

```
sudo ufw allow in on virbr1
sudo ufw reload
```

But you need to figure out the correct interface name via `ifconfig`.

In my case I did `minikube ip` to realize the interface was `virbr1`

I found the solution because in the past I had connectivity problems with docker which got resolved with `sudo ufw allow in on docker0`

Comment: This fixed my issue with mounting completely

Answer (score 2):

Just to generalize the great solution by Leo:

```sh
ip r g $(minikube ip)|awk '{print $3}'|head -n1|xargs sudo ufw allow in on
sudo ufw reload
```

This gets the minikube ip, looks up the interface and adds that to firewall rules.

Hope that helps anyone. And thanks Leo.

Comment: This fixed my issue with mounting completely